# Is there a better way to to make async API calls using the @wordpress/data module?

Tags: block-editor

Before posting here, I posted this to both reddit (it was removed as spam for some reason) and the [gutenberg github discussions](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/41537) but didn't get any response. If there's a better place for me to ask, please let me know before downvoting.

I am working on understanding the `@wordpress/data module`. One of the tasks I set myself was to create a demo app that would (essentially) have two parts:

- a button a user could click on
- a list where articles would be displayed that are fetched from an external API

The list of articles would start out empty. Then when the user clicks the button, the list is populated. The project works, but I'm not sure I've written the functionality in the most efficient way and could use a double check. For reference, I used [the official docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/) and [Darren Ethier's series of articles](https://unfoldingneurons.com/series/practical-overview-of-wp-data) on the subject.

After registering a working block, I wrote this small react app (I've merged everything into one file here for simplicity). I have a [working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-goldberg-rb2b5z?file=/src/App.js).

I have the following questions that hopefully you all can help me understand better

- I understand that in the `ArticleList` component, `useSelect` starts with articles as an empty array from state and then updates when state changes. However, why is it not necessary to pass state into the `getArticles` selector?
- In the `getArticles` resolver, is it correct to use the `hasFinishedResolution` selector? This seemed to be the only way I could get the `DEFAULT_STATE` to update in the way I wanted.
- I would've thought that I should use some kind of dispatch on the click handler for the button. However, I couldn't seem to create an action creator that made sense (to me) which would work. Is using a select method in a click handler like this valid or an anti-pattern?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

```
import { render } from '@wordpress/element'

import { createReduxStore, register, useSelect, dispatch, select, } from '@wordpress/data'

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  articles: [],
}

const actions = {
  fetchFromAPI(path) {
    return {
      type: 'FETCH_FROM_API',
      path
    }
  },
  setArticles(articles) {
    return {
      type: 'SET_ARTICLES',
      payload: articles
    }
  }
}

const store = createReduxStore('my/data-demo', {

  // these are action creators. they return an action object with a type and arbitrary state data
  // they help the app maintain an immutable state
  // they are determined by the dispatch method calls
  actions,

  controls: {
    FETCH_FROM_API: async (action) => {
      return await fetch(action.path).then(res => res.json()).catch(err => console.log({ err }))
    },
  },

  selectors: {
    // the state is implied. it doesn't need to be passed when the selector is called
    getArticles(state) {
      return state.articles
    }
  },

  resolvers: {
    /**
     * 
     * You can pass an arbitrary number of arguments here.
     * The first will always be the state. After that, you can use anything
     * The other arguments _do not_ need to be represented in the selector function. However, that selector must return state
     * 
     * See here for info on hasFinishedResolution - https://unfoldingneurons.com/2020/wordpress-data-store-properties-resolvers
     * 
     * @param {*} state 
     * @param {*} test 
     * @returns 
     */
    *getArticles(state, test) {
      const path = 'https://today.uconn.edu/wp-rest/wp/v2/posts'
      const articles = yield actions.fetchFromAPI(path)

      // wait for the resolver to finish before yielding
      const hasFinishedResolving = select('my/data-demo').hasFinishedResolution('getArticles')

      if (hasFinishedResolving) {
        yield actions.setArticles(articles)
      }

      return
    }
  },

  // the reducer function returns new immutable copies of the state
  // there should be no mutations
  // once the dispatch method is called, the reducer determines how to create a new state object
  reducer: (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_ARTICLES': {
        return {
          ...state,
          articles: action.payload
        }
      }
      case 'FETCH_FROM_API':
        return {
          ...state,
          path: action.payload,
        }
      // if there is no matching action return the state
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
})

register(store)

const ArticleList = ({ state, ...props }) => {

  const { articles } = state

  // selected articles will update when the state changes from the button click
  const selectedArticles = useSelect((select) => {
    // don't pass the state here...
    return select('my/data-demo').getArticles()
  }, [ articles ])

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Latest Articles</h1>
      {
        selectedArticles && (
          <ul>
            {
              selectedArticles.map((article, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{article.title.rendered}</li>
              })
            }
          </ul>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => select('my/data-demo').getArticles(DEFAULT_STATE) }
          >GET Articles</button>
          <ArticleList state={DEFAULT_STATE} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```